# I require assistance with the BMI formula, did I do the formula wrong?

Tags: python

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.  I've looked up similar topics and have found other users having similar BMI formulas.  When I put in my test numbers (160 for weight and 6 for height), I get 3124.444444444445, which is not supposed to be the answer.  I swear I missed something important or I input a really cruddy version of the BMI formula.

```
weight = int(input("Insert weight here (in pounds): "))
height = float(input("Insert height here (in inches): "))

bmi = float((weight / (height * height)) * 703)
print("Your bmi is: ", bmi)
```

EDIT: Okay, I made a stupid mistake.  Ah well, thanks for the help mates.

Comment: Are you sure `height` is only `6` inches?

Comment: ;~; How did I miss this?  Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need height in inches: that's 72 inches for 6 feet tall.

This correction should give you a BMI of about 21.70

Comment: Fuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu~ Oh crap!  How did I miss this?!?

Comment: Can't resist: read your own user instructions!  :-)  Been there, done that, got the t-shirt collection.

Answer (score -1):

You've set the formula up wrong. Check your parenthesis, and if you can't find the error, check your assumptions about how parenthesis work.

Prune is also right.

Also you might want to check into how to limit your answer to a given precision as most folks will want BMI to be something like "12.5", not "32.333333333333333333333333333333333333333333".

Comment: I think the formula is correct; it's the input that needs correction.

Comment: Google it. 

The formulas I found were, for pounds ((weight * 703)/(height*height))

Comment: which is algebraically equivalent to what OP coded.